# Photon-wise justification of chosen compensation crystal length in SPDC

Tags: photons, quantum-entanglement, non-linear-optics

I know a compensation crystal in SPDC schemas serves the temporal walk-off erasment purpose. However, I am not sure why half the length of the original crystal is opted for. I read an [article](https://doi.org/10.1109/JSTQE.2003.820927) that provides an explanation in terms of overlapping wave functions, which makes sense to me. However, I would like to find a more corpuscular explanation? In [this article](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.69.013807) they claimed that, when having two points in which the photon pair is being generated, which are also symetrically displaced from the crystal center, the vertical and horizontal photons, belonging to different generation points, are exchanged, due to the compensation crystal.

[image: Temporal difference of generated photon pairs in two distinc points A and B]

But when I did calculations for symetrical geometry, it is $A = \frac{L}{2} - x$ and $B = \frac{L}{2} + x$, I didn't get temporal overlap. There is still a temporal difference of $\delta t = x\left(\frac{1}{v_e} + \frac{1}{v_o}\right)$, where $v_e$, $v_o$ are extraordinary, ordinary beam velocities.

[image: Propagation of 2 photon pairs (red originated in point A, blue originated in point B)]

I might have missunderstood the explanation. How to justify the chossen crystal length ($L/2$)?